# SQL Server Kubernetes StatefulSet deployment not ready

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes

I am trying to configure my Kubernetes deployment for SQL Server database to be `StatefulSet` to connect to my Web API.

This isw my `.Yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: firstone-mssql-statefulset
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: "firstone-mssql-service"
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: firstone-mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: firstone-mssql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: firstoneSQL
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "500m"
        ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
        env:
            - name: MSSQL_PID
              value: "Developer"
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "Y"
            - name: SA_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: firstone-mssql
                  key: SA_PASSWORD 
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql 
              name: data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
         name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: firstone-mssql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: firstone-mssql
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
```

When running the following command to get statefulsets

```
kubectl get statefulsets
```

I got the following

```
NAME                         READY   AGE
firstone-mssql-statefulset   0/1     12m
```

**Update**

When running the following command to get pods

```
kubectl get pods
```

I got the following

```
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
```

Comment: `memory: "128Mi"`? As per [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) requirements, _At least 2GB of RAM (3.25 GB prior to 2017-CU2)._

Comment: I changed this but it's still not working. the same error appears.

Comment: If you `kubectl logs <your-pod-name>` what error(s) does it report?

Comment: there are no pods created. I updated the question with `kubectl get pods` output

Comment: please run `kubectl describe statefulset <your statefulset name>` and paste the results to the question.

Comment: thank you @MikołajGłodziak I did `kubectl describe statefulset <your statefulset name>` and I found the issue I will post the issue and the answer to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @MikołajGłodziak for his comment.

I did `kubectl describe statefulset <your statefulset name>` and found the following issue

```
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                    From                    Message
  ----     ------        ----                   ----                    -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  15h (x31 over 16h)     statefulset-controller  create Pod firstone-mssql-statefulset-0 in StatefulSet firstone-mssql-statefulset failed error: Pod "firstone-mssql-statefulset-0" is invalid: spec.containers[0].name: Invalid value: "firstoneSQL": a lowercase RFC 1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

the issue is in the spec-> container-> name

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: firstoneSQL <-- this is wrong label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character case
```

by changing this uppercase character to lower case character the statefulset created with ready status

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: firstone-sql
```